# Explain this proof in more details

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

The following is the proposition 3.3 of folland "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis" book. please Explain its proof in more details:

I do not know the cause of contradiction. that is, how maximality is violated?

[image]

Comment: You might get better answers if you specify what you don't understand.

Comment: I do not know the cause of contradiction.

Comment: "The following" has no substance, apart from the external reference to 3.3. Why not tell literally what the issue is?

Comment: If this $u$ were orthogonal, then by the argument they gave, you could adjoin the cyclic subspace generated by it to the collection you've chosen, which would mean that the collection you've chosen is not maximal. This is how Zorn's Lemma is typically used. A similar application is proving the existence of a complete orthonormal system in an arbitrary Hilbert space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $u$ is orthogonal to all $M_a$s. Then the cyclic rep $U$ generated by $u$ is orthogonal to the $M_a$s.

Therefore the collection $\{M_a\}_{a\in\cal A}\cup\{U\}$ is *also* a collection of mutually orthogonal cyclic reps, and it is *strictly greater* than the collection $\{M_a\}_{a\in\cal A}$. (The partial order here is inclusion.) But our hypothesis was that $\{M_a\}_{a\in\cal A}$ was the *greatest* possible collection of mutually orthogonal cyclic reps. How can it be the greatest possible when there is one greater? It can't be - that's a contradiction!